# MySQL: Combing multiple tables in a search

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of SQL which searches a website's contents tables and returns the results based on relevance:

```
SELECT *, 
( (1.3 * (MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+query+string' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.6 * (MATCH(txtContent) AGAINST ('+query+string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance 
FROM content 
WHERE (MATCH(strTitle,txtContent) AGAINST ('+query+string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

I need to expand this to include 2 other tables.

I need to search 2 fields of a table trade_members:

> company_name | contact_name

and 2 fields of a table news:

> news_title | news_content

and bring the results back in one fell swoop ordered by relevance. How can I go about incorporating these tables to my results?

Comment: Do you mean search using `JOIN` tables?

Comment: Not really, the way I see it, I would need to combine the 2 searchable columns from each of the 3 tables into a virtual table and then perform the above query on it so I get just a single set of results showing everything

Comment: It sounds like you could use a UNION (assuming I understand what you are wanting).  A UNION can combine results from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a UNION of three selects. But let's disect thes first.

So far you've got

```
SELECT *, {formula} AS relevance FROM content WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

You'll now need two additional selects:

```
SELECT *, {formula} AS relevance FROM trade_members WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
SELECT *, {formula} AS relevance FROM news WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

If you run those three statements separately, you'll see that they return different columns. You will then have to unify those columns. Without more detail about the table structure I can only give you a hint of what that could look like.

```
SELECT 'content' as type, contentID as id, strTitle     as title, txtContent   as content, {formula} AS relevance FROM content WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
SELECT 'member'  as type, memberID  as id, company_name as title, contact_name as content, {formula} AS relevance FROM trade_members WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
SELECT 'news'    as type, newsID    as id, news_title   as title, news_content as content, {formula} AS relevance FROM news WHERE {cond} ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Now all three selects should give you a similarly looking result - more to the point: you should see the same column names for all three of them, and each row should allow you to identify which data in your database it represents, e.g.: This is content 17, that is company 33 and that is news 1776.

Now you can do a union on all three:

```
(1st select) UNION (2nd select) UNION (3rd select) ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Please note, however that this may be pretty slow, because you're actually creating **four** temp tables that need to be file sorted... you may experiment with how getting rid of the ordering of the three basic selects affect performance - since they're not actually needed.